# Launch React-Native apps with fbsimctl on multiple devices

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

Thanks to [fbsimctl](https://github.com/facebook/FBSimulatorControl/tree/master/fbsimctl) we can launch multiple iOS simulators running multiple iOS-versions at the same time. Any ideas how to launch ReactNative-projects on all iOS-simulators simultanously?

When i launch the app with "`react-native run-ios`" it will only appear on the very first simulator that was launched. When i launch via XCode all other simulators will shutdown automatically except this one that was selected in the XCode launch-bar.

In the README is stated the command:

```
fbsimctl launch com.facebook.someapp
```

I replaced the app-id to mine and it did not help, but will output something like:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.FBSimulatorControl Code=0 "App
>   com.myown.appid can't be launched as it isn't installed"

It is also mentioned to call

```
fbsimctl install Someapp.app
```

I tried it with an exported IPA directly out of XCode. It produces:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.FBSimulatorControl Code=0 "Could not
>   determine Application information for path
>   /private/var/folders/cj/c_zjt5x12ps_6q93t023qc4w0000gn/T/61863B0A-89D3-4002-ACC4-D31EC256BA50-70447-0000472A108998F9/Payload/XXXXXX.app"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Could not determine Application
>   information for path
>   /private/var/folders/cj/c_zjt5x12ps_6q93t023qc4w0000gn/T/61863B0A-89D3-4002-ACC4-D31EC256BA50-70447-0000472A108998F9/Payload/XXXXXX.app

Has anyone used it? For android i find it very usefully being able to launch several different simulators and launch the app with only one command on all these "devices".

Comment: If you get "unable to boot device in current state booted" then it's a problem with xcode and after restarting the xcode everything will work fine... But there is a simpler way to regain the power by simply shutting down the simulators the command required is xcrun simctl shutdown "iPhone 6 Plus"  and you can get the list of simulators by xcrun simctl list...

Answer (score 0):

> fbsimctl install Someapp.app
>   To use this command, you must have a build of your app for the simulator (.app file). You can create it via Xcode or via command line (use as target 
>    iOS Simulator)

It's preferable to start with simulators and .app, because using real devices and .ipa is much more complicated because of the profiling